# how can i select the time in appium

Tags: java, android, appium, timepicker

[image][image: this image show the ui of the elements in the circle]

I am trying the

1. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='5']"));`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper[@content-desc='5']"));`
3. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper[@content-desc='5']")).click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper\").instance(2)").click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper\").instance(1)").click();

First link for hour and second for minute
for hour: instance 0 means select the 1 hr from watch and instance 1 for select the 2 hr from watch and so on........
for min.:-  instance 0 means select the 00 min from watch and instance 1 for select the 0 5min from watch and so on..........

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the element using classname, store it in a List and access it using either its index or some attribute.

```
List <WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.classname("android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper"))
```

After this, iterate the list and perform the action

Comment: can u please elaborate how can i iterate

Comment: After the above line, you will get all the elements in a list. So if you want to access a particular element you can use the "list.get(i)" method.  For eg: if you want to select the time as 10, then you can use:      list.get(9).click().  This will set the time as 10 in your time picker.